# how to read and modify this bash script to check for 2 arguments instead of 1?

Tags: bash

I know php programming but I am not familiar with bash script programming syntax.

I have this code snippet

```
EXPECTEDARGS=0
if [ $# -ne $EXPECTEDARGS -o "x$0" == "x"  -o $0 == "bash" ]; then
  echo "Usage:"
  echo "   Parameter 1: argument 1 missing"
  exit 1
fi
```

This correctly checks for at least 1 argument.

I want to understand what this code snippet means **line by line**. So far, I can only make out that EXPECTEDARGS is a variable.

After understanding the code snippet, I want to modify it to check for 2 arguments.

The code snippet will be in a github gist.

I aim to execute the script using

```
bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/gist/4491019)" <arg1> <arg2>
```

without the <> symbols of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- $# number of arguments.
- $0 shell script name
- $1,$2,...,$n argument 1, 2, etc
- [ condition ] test one or more conditions, -ne not equal, -eq equal, -gt greater than, -lt lesser than, -o or, = compare string/number
- "x$0" = x check if script name/prog name is empty

if you want to know more, save the script as a file and try to print stuff with `echo`. Run the script with:

```
bash -c ./script.sh
```

or

```
bash script.sh
```

to mimic the behaviour of bash+curl

`[ ]` or `test` is a good example, they are just a program, actually the same program, while checking $0 or argv[0] in C, they behave a little bit different.

```
$ ls -l /bin/test /bin/\[
-r-xr-xr-x  2 root  wheel  43120 Dec 11  2011 /bin/[*
-r-xr-xr-x  2 root  wheel  43120 Dec 11  2011 /bin/test*
```

If you run `[ 2 -gt 1 ]; echo $?` it will print 0 in your terminal, 0 means success everything else means failure. If you call `test` instead: `test 2 -gt 1; echo $?` it also print 0.

so `if` just runs a program and checks the exit code, you can also do:

```
if true; then
    echo success
fi

if false; then
    echo fail
fi

true; echo $?; false; echo $?
```

will print: success, 0, 1

Answer (score 1):

> if [ $# -ne $EXPECTEDARGS -o "x$0" == "x"  -o $0 == "bash" ]; then

- `$#`  - The total number of arguments to the script.
- `"x$0" == "x"` - To check whether `$0` is null/empty.
- `$0` - the First argument , which is always the script name. So the condition of checking with string 'bash' will return false unless your scriptname is **bash**.
- `-o` - OR operator

Rest is just the `echo` statement that are output to console, if the `if` statement was true. Syntax on `if` in bash is

```
if [ <condition> ]; then
   # ... Statements
fi
```

To check for number of arguments to be 2 you just need the following -

```
EXPECTEDARGS=2
if [ $# -ne $EXPECTEDARGS ]; then
     # number of arguments are not 2, display usage etc, here
fi
```

[Check the bash reference manual for more info](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html).

Answer (score 1):

If number of arguments is not equal (`ne`) to the EXPECTEDARGS or (`-o`) script name is the empty string  (`"x$0" == "x"`) or (`-o`) script name is `bash` then report usage and exit. The script name tests are probably testing if the invocation is through a script file rather than piping or $(cat script) kind of stuff.

Answer (score 1):

1. $# - Stores the number of command-line arguments that were passed to
   the shell program.
2. $0 - points to the filename of the script.

To make your script check for 2 arguments, Make the below changes

```
EXPECTEDARGS=2
if [ $# -lt $EXPECTEDARGS -o "x$0" == "x"  -o $0 == "bash" ]; then
```

Comment: i don't think you should use both `[ ]` and `test`, they are just different name of the same program.